# How to sort a map by key using comparator

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap`:

```java
Map<Car, Integer> vehicles = new HashMap<Car, Integer>();
```

I need to return the cheapest `Car` in the map using streams. `Car` has a getter that returns price:

```java
double calcCost() {
    return price;
}
```

I cannot use `Comparator` outside the stream, I must use it inside.

Here's what I tried:

```java
this.vehicles
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparing(Car::calcCost)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Stream.sorted()` method can be directly used with `Comparator.comparing()` and its variations (including `comparingDouble()` that is designed to work with `double` primitives).

If you need to return only the cheapest `Car`, you can write:

```java
Optional<Car> cheapestCarOpt = this.vehicles.keySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Car::calcCost))
    .findFirst();
```

Otherwise, if full entry (key + value) is required, the following code should work:

```java
Optional<Map.Entry<Car, Integer>> cheapestCarEntryOpt =  this.vehicles.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.getKey().calcCost()))
    .findFirst();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of using `sorted` and `findFirst` it's better to use `min(...)`. The same `Comparator` can be used.

Comment: @RobSpoor As we do not know the OP's problem and limitations we can't tell them for sure which is 'better' or 'worse'. The current solution allows more flexibility as you can get not only 1 min value but "top N min values" if needed. The performance difference depends on the number of items and can be negligible. Anyway, the answers aims to fix the actual problem in the OP's attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using

```
vehicles.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .min(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparing(Car::calcCost))
```

but if you need to find the minimum price of the car frequently, I recommend you use [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of HashMap